# How do I convert a dataframe to JSON and write to kafka topic with key

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming-kafka

I'm trying to write a dataframe to kafka in JSON format and add a key to the data frame in Scala, i'm currently working with this sample from the kafka-spark:

```
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
       .write
       .format("kafka")
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
       .option("topic", "topic1")
       .save()
```

Is there a `to_json` method that can be used (instead of the `json(path)` option which I believe writes out to a file in JSON format) and is there a `key` option that can be used to replace the `null` value with an actual key.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the `to_json` SQL function to convert your columns into a JSON.

See Scala code below which is also making use of the [Spark SQL built-in function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/api/sql/index.html#struct) `struct` in Spark version 2.4.5. Just make sure that your are naming your columns as `key` and `value` or applying corresponding aliases in your `selectExpr`.

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, struct, to_json}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {

  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .appName("myAppName")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()

  // create DataFrame
  import spark.implicits._
  val df = Seq((3, "Alice"), (5, "Bob")).toDF("age", "name")
  df.show(false)

  // convert columns into json string
  val df2 = df.select(col("name"),to_json(struct($"*"))).toDF("key", "value")
  df2.show(false)

  // +-----+------------------------+
  // |key  |value                   |
  // +-----+------------------------+
  // |Alice|{"age":3,"name":"Alice"}|
  // |Bob  |{"age":5,"name":"Bob"}  |
  // +-----+------------------------+

  // write to Kafka with jsonString as value
  df2.selectExpr("key", "value")
    .write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
    .option("topic", "test-topic")
    .save()

}
```

This will return the following data into your Kafka topic:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --property print.key=true --property print.value=true --topic test-topic
Alice   {"age":3,"name":"Alice"}
Bob     {"age":5,"name":"Bob"}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a minimal example in scala. Let's say you have a dataframe `df` with columns `x` and `y`. Here's a minimal example:

```
val dataDS = df
    .select(
        $"x".cast(StringType),
        $"y".cast(StringType)
    )
    .toJSON
    .withColumn("key", lit("keyname"))

dataDS   
    .write
    .format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "servername:port")
    .option("topic", "topicname")
    .save()
```

Remember you need the `spark-sql-kafka` library: e.g. for `spark-shell` is loaded with

```
spark-shell --packages "org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.0.1"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `toJSON()` method on dataframe to convert your record to json message.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('user_first_name','user_last_nmae',100)], ['first_name','last_name','ID'])

import json
from datetime import datetime
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
json_df = json.loads(df.withColumn('date_as_key', lit(datetime.now().date())).toJSON().first())
print json_df

{u'date_as_key': u'2019-07-29', u'first_name': u'user_first_name', u'last_name': u'user_last_nmae', u'ID': 100}
```

**Your code may be like this**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
df.withColumn('key', lit(datetime.now())).toJSON()
       .write
       .format("kafka")
       .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2")
       .option("topic", "topic1")
       .save()
```

**Scala**:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
someDF.withColumn("key",lit("name")).show() // replace "name" with your variable
 someDF.withColumn("key",lit("name")).toJSON.first() // toJSON is available as variable on dataframe in Scala

 someDF.withColumn("key",lit("name")).toJSON.first()
res5: String = {"number":8,"word":"bat","key":"name"}
```

Comment: I just modified the question to add that i'm doing this in Scala. But regardless, for adding the key, what if the key is a variable? can I parse variables in the selectExpr?
`selectExpr("CAST("+variable+" AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").toJSON()`

Comment: I am assuming you want to add a key column that is a variable to your message, updated the answer

Comment: This is what I am aiming to do, but in scala:
http://bigdatums.net/2017/05/21/send-key-value-messages-kafka-console-producer/
Also, it seems like `toJSON()` is not a valid function in scala