# How to send pyspark dataframe to kafka topic?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-kafka-integration

pyspark version - 2.4.7
kafka version - 2.13_3.2.0

Hi, I am new to pyspark and streaming properties. I have come across few resources in the internet, but still I am not able to figure out how to send a pyspark data frame to a kafka broker. I need to write a producer code.
I am reading the data from a csv file and trying to send it to kafka topic. Please help me out with the code and the configurations.

```
import findspark
findspark.init("/usr/local/spark")
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import os
from kafka import KafkaProducer

import csv

def spark_session():
    '''
    Description:
        To open a spark session. Returns a spark session object.
    '''
    spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Test_Kafka_Producer") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .getOrCreate()
    
    return spark
   
if __name__ == '__main__':

    spark = spark_session()
    topic = "Kafkatest"
    spark_version = '2.4.7'
    os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.13:{}'.format(spark_version)
 
    #producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
                       #value_serializer= lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))

    df1 = spark.read.csv("annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional-size-bands-csv.csv", inferSchema = True, header = True)
    df1.show(10)

    print("sending df===========")

    df1.write \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
    .option("topic", topic) \
    .save()

    print("End------")
```

The error that I am encountering for this bit of code is
`py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o41.save. : org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deployment section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Spark to read a CSV file and run a Kafka Producer in Python (I see you already tried to import KafkaProducer, which should have worked)

E.g

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'], value_serializer= lambda x: x.encode('utf-8'))
with open("annual-enterprise-survey-2020-financial-year-provisional-size-bands-csv.csv") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if i > 0:
            producer.send(topic, line)
producer.flush()
```

---

But if `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` doesn't work, as it looks like it doesn't, you should use the same option on the CLI

```
spark-submit --packages ... app.py
```

Or you can use `config("spark.jars.packages", "...")` on the session, as shown below.

---

You'll also need to ensure that the Kafka dataframe only has the mentioned schema, as per [the documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka) (topic, key, value, etc). In other words, all CSV columns should be encoded as one string, so you'd be better off using `spark.read.text` and filtering out the first header row before you produce anything

Example

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

scala_version = '2.12'  # TODO: Ensure this is correct
spark_version = '3.2.1'
packages = [
    f'org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_{scala_version}:{spark_version}',
    'org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:3.2.0'
]
spark = SparkSession.builder\
   .master("local")\
   .appName("kafka-example")\
   .config("spark.jars.packages", ",".join(packages))\
   .getOrCreate()

# Read all lines into a single value dataframe  with column 'value'
# TODO: Replace with real file. 
df = spark.read.text('file:///tmp/data.csv')

# TODO: Remove the file header, if it exists

# Write
df.write.format("kafka")\
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
  .option("topic", "foobar")\
  .save()
```

Verified on host with

```
$ kcat -b localhost:9092 -C -t foobar
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. But I would be extremely greatfull if you could send me a link of exactly how to encode it. As I said I am fairly new to pyspark-kafka streaming. Code bits will help a lot.

Comment: Like I said, `spark.read.text` will already have a single column dataframe that can be produced

Comment: Thanks for the code. I actually did it like this before but this doesn't solve my problem. As I will be solely working on pyspark dfs and everytime converting them to csv's for streaming will not be optimised solution. I have tried reading csv just for example. Sending dataframe is concern for me.

Comment: Once again, `spark.read.text` is what you should try. However, if you're only ever going to be reading a local csv file, then there's nothing to "stream" or "optimize". Adding pyspark will be slower with added JVM overhead for reading local files rather than directly looping them in Python

Comment: @subh I've added a working Spark example

Comment: Thanks a lot or your code. It works fine. U saved me in job today!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write df directly but does it follow the Kafka required schema where value column is necessary

Please check [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html#writing-data-to-kafka) link for details and you might then need to encode your dataframe into value column to send it to Kafka

Comment: The error has nothing to do with the dataframe encoding

Comment: I have gone through this one, but I am not understanding how do I change my usual dataframe having differnt columns obtained from reading a csv, to a spark streaming df?

Comment: Can you try using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57258461/how-do-i-convert-a-dataframe-to-json-and-write-to-kafka-topic-with-key) link